# Use react-router for SSR: client sends a new request to server for every route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router, server-side-rendering

I'm working in a `Meteor` + `React` project that requires using `react-router` for server-side rendering (SSR). The current `react-router` version is `v3` and I followed a tutorial about SSR [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/13-server-rendering). The steps in summary are:

- Create a common routes file
- Include the routes file in client-side router

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
// import routes and pass them into <Router/>
import routes from './modules/routes'

render(
  <Router routes={routes} history={browserHistory}/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

- In the server-side: match the routes to the url, render the right component for each route

```js
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  // match the routes to the url
  match({ routes: routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirect, props) => {
    // `RouterContext` is what the `Router` renders. `Router` keeps these
    // `props` in its state as it listens to `browserHistory`. But on the
    // server our app is stateless, so we need to use `match` to
    // get these props before rendering.
    const appHtml = renderToString(<RouterContext {...props}/>)

    // dump the HTML into a template, lots of ways to do this, but none are
    // really influenced by React Router, so we're just using a little
    // function, `renderPage`
    res.send(renderPage(appHtml))
  })
})

function renderPage(appHtml) {
  return `
    <!doctype html public="storage">
    <html>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
    <title>My First React Router App</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet href=/index.css>
    <div id=app>${appHtml}</div>
    <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
   `
}
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(app);
```

The problem here is that every time I navigate to a new route in client-side, it sends a new request to server to get the rendered page. In the tutorial app, there's only a single initial request that is sent to server, from that time the client will take over and handle routing (which is the correct/expected behaviour).
PS: I use `react-router`'s `<Link />` component for links to routes. This is how I render them:

```html
<div className="row">
    <div className="eight columns offset-by-two">
      <nav className="appFooter-nav">
        <Link to="/listeners" className="appFooter-nav-link">Life Guides</Link>
        <Link to="/mission" className="appFooter-nav-link">Mission</Link>
        <Link to="/contact" className="appFooter-nav-link">Contact</Link>
        <Link to="/legals" className="appFooter-nav-link">Legals</Link>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how it's rendered:
[image]

Comment: can you show how are you rendering your `a` in the component where you are encountering the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Panther, I updated my post with how I'm rendering my links.

Comment: Could not figure out. Looks like your `react-router` did not kick in after the code is rendered in the browser. How does the `a` tag looks in the rendered html ?

Comment: @Panther I updated my post with how the rendered HTML look.

Comment: Hey did you evolve on this? @sonlexqt

Comment: can only advice this great article http://julian.io/server-side-rendering-ssr-in-meteor/ which explains a lot on router configuration for SSR in meteor/react

Answer (score 0):

This is because you add html attributes to the `<Link/>` Component

```
example:
<Link to="/listeners" className="appFooter-nav-link">Life Guides</Link>
                      ^ you are not supposed to add className
```

`<Link/>` Component of react-router-dom should not have any props other than `to`, `replace`, `innerRef` and `component` otherwise will produce unexpected outcome.

See react-router-dom reference for the [Link](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink) component

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink